# Creating code snippets in Visual Studio Code using EBNF

Tags: visual-studio-code, code-snippets, ebnf

[Here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets#_grammar) they say we can generate code using EBNF but I don't understand how, it seems to only accept JSON. Does anyone know how to do it?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The link that you mentioned, does **not** say that we can generate a new snippet using EBNF.

they have documented something like :

> Below is the EBNF (extended Backus-Naur form) for snippets

And then.. they have given EBNF for snippets.

```
any         ::= tabstop | placeholder | choice | variable | text
tabstop     ::= '$' int | '${' int '}'
placeholder ::= '${' int ':' any '}'
choice      ::= '${' int '|' text (',' text)* '|}'
variable    ::= '$' var | '${' var }'
                | '${' var ':' any '}'
                | '${' var '/' regex '/' (format | text)+ '/' options '}'
format      ::= '$' int | '${' int '}'
                | '${' int ':' '/upcase' | '/downcase' | '/capitalize' '}'
                | '${' int ':+' if '}'
                | '${' int ':?' if ':' else '}'
                | '${' int ':-' else '}' | '${' int ':' else '}'
regex       ::= JavaScript Regular Expression value (ctor-string)
options     ::= JavaScript Regular Expression option (ctor-options)
var         ::= [_a-zA-Z] [_a-zA-Z0-9]*
int         ::= [0-9]+
text        ::= .*
```

It tells what is the possible combination and keywords which are accepted by the Snippet. It is indeed JSON format I can say by looking at the EBNF. The snippet creation is limited to this at the moment. we can not generate advanced snippet in the current release (Version 1.24).

Please read through the document to gether some more information on how to make a new snippet with variables given and the replacement logic. Thanks.